# Is deleting the tail of a vector (through erase) memory efficient?

Tags: c++, stl

When doing `v.erase(some_iterator);`

Are implementations smart enough to not do any reallocations/bytes-copying since we could just update the size? (Unlike when erasing strictly inner elements.)

Comment: The only copy/move are from elements after your iterator (to remove the "hole" done by `erase`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erasing from an `std::vector` does not invalidate iterators and references to the elements before the first erased element.

So if you delete only the last element, it is guaranteed that all of the other elements stay where they are, they are not moved around or copied.

However, note that erasing from an `std::vector` generally only changes its size, not its capacity, so the memory the old objects lived in is still owned by the `vector`. This is for performance reasons and nothing to worry about (unless you run out of RAM).

Also, the erased objects are of course properly destructed, so if they are not trivially destructable, their destructors must be run in addition to adjusting the `vector`'s size.

Comment: in any case the destructor will be called, which depeding on the type can be quite something, no? I think "just updating the size" as proposed by OP isnt sufficient.

Comment: @tobi303 Of course, I read the question as "Does it touch the other elements?". I'll add a remark though.

Comment: yes sure, the answer is fine with me, just wanted to note that reallocations isnt the only thing that happens wehn erasing

Answer (score 0):

The vector capacity is not changed through erase. Just the pointer to end is changed. Use shrink_to_fit (C++11) to really free memory

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  size_t tmp [5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<size_t> vec (tmp, tmp+5);
  std::cout << "vec.capacity () == " << vec.capacity () << std::endl;
  std::vector<size_t>::iterator i (&vec [3]);
  vec.erase (i, vec.end ());
  std::cout << "vec.capacity () after erase == " << vec.capacity () << std::endl;
  vec.shrink_to_fit ();
  std::cout << "vec.capacity () after shrink_to_fit == " << vec.capacity () << std::endl;
}
```

will output :

```
vec.capacity () == 5
vec.capacity () after erase == 5
vec.capacity () after shrink_to_fit == 3
```